# Wifi stopped working after Update 20.04

Tags: wireless, 20.04, iwlwifi

I installed an update using UI and after that the wifi is not working.

I'm able to scan available wifi networks using `iw` but from UI it shows no network available.
`nmcli d` shows wifi state unavailable.

My wireless card is *Intel Corporation Wireless-AC 9462*

Any ideas on how to fix this?

Comment: Please post what you tried, links you followed.

Comment: @sancho.sReinstateMonicaCellio I don't exactly have the links, but I've been googling all over since 2 days and tried lots of different things. I've backported `iwlwifi` driver but that didn't change anything.  `rfkill` also shows all unblocked. `nmcli radio` shows everything enabled. restarted network manager (obviously). Can't paste all logs here because i'm typing this from a different machine

Comment: from `/var/log/syslog` looks like iwd service is not able to start, maybe this can be a useful information.